# Run-time error '91' in vba macro

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use multiple ifs to find certain data points, then paste the value from a certain column into another sheet. I am getting run-tim Error 91. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I remove the And statement and change from Rows to cells it works fine, but the way I introduced And seems to be the problem.

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim Line As Long
Dim NewRange As Range
Dim MyCount As Long
MyCount = 1


For Line = 1 To 10000 Step 1
  If Cells(Line, 2) = "Farm2" And Cells(Line, 12) = "new" Then
      Set NewRange = Cells(Line, 1)
      End If

Next Line

NewRange.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Farm2").Range("B18:B" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
```

Comment: Are you trying to copy more than one line? If so you should `Exit For` once you've found a match. If not, then the copy should be in the loop's `If` statement. btw, there are better ways of finding the next available blank row than what you are currently using.

Answer (score 3):

Your code assumes that both the conditions are met and that `NewRange` has been set. If the conditions aren't met and `NewRange` hasn't been set then the final line will cause an error because there is no range object to copy.

You can test for this by using something like:

```
If Not NewRange Is Nothing Then
    NewRange.Copy Destination:=Worksheets("Farm2").Range("B18:B" & Rows.Count).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
Else
    MsgBox "NewRange has not been set!"
End If
```

---

More importantly, consider [Jeeped's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35140766/run-time-error-91-in-vba-macro/35140916#comment58002212_35140766) about the structure of your code - specifically about how you're working within your loop.